# NSNotification removeObserver problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am either brain damaged or I am lacking of some understending of NSNotificationCenter

The problem is that if I create an observer and in the next line will try to delete it like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(removeAllVisibleMapViews) name:@"ClearVisibleMaps" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"ClearVisibleMaps"];
```

I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <MyApp 0x592db70> for the key path "ClearVisibleMaps" from <NSNotificationCenter 0x4e0fbb0> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

I add and remove observer line after line just to make a point. In my code I will be using remove in the dealloc.

So any ideas why it does tell me that I didn't add and observer in the first place?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're removing observer for keypath, not for notification name. The removal should be something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"ClearVisibleMaps"
                                              object:nil];
```

Comment: thanks, so it's true I am brain damaged :-) hehe at least today.