# Xcode 7 / Swift 2 Storyboard crash - Beta 1 & 4

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7-beta4

Without warning, my xcode app suddenly started to crash when I clicked on the storyboard file. With some digging, I found many people said to do this:

```
"Go to

/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

 and remove the profiles in there. Restart Xcode and it should work!"
```

When I search for this folder in finder, the go to folder function, it says it can't be found. Others say to clear colorPickers, but that still didn't work for me. Xcode crashes for me in both beta 1 and 4 (which I have). I could really use some help.

***UPDATE*** This error message also comes up in the warning notifications:
Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Here is the pop-up when it crashes:

```
Process:               Xcode [6312]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.0 (8163.8)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8163008000000000~7
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [6312]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-07-27 11:55:06.545 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A225f)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        CCD99EAB-C0B0-7A00-2973-B979C02BC5E7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       AB09C466-CD98-48A5-B0DE-2D18DB8F52CB

Time Awake Since Boot: 5500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3400 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A152u
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-8152.3/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBPlatformToolFailureHandler.m:315
Details:  Failed to determine the values for ibLayoutInset, intrinsicContentSize, baselineOffsetFromBottom, firstBaselineOffsetFromTop, ibLayoutMargins, ibLeftBarButtonItemTitleRects, ibRightBarButtonItemTitleRects, ibLeftBarButtonItemFrames, ibRightBarButtonItemFrames, and ibTitleViewFrame of IBUINavigationBar.

Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. If you choose to file a crash report or Radar for this issue, please zip and attach the diagnostics at "/var/folders/p7/2jw_957n4t12wkx9hm4vn_tc0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-07-27_11-55-06_310000" to your crash report.

Exception name: IBPlatformToolFailureException
Exception reason: The agent crashed

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <AVPlayerViewController 0x7c84ee00> for the key path "playerController.hasEnabledAudio" from <AVPlayerViewController 0x7c84ee00> because it is not registered as an observer.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 169 - Device: iPad 2 - Runtime: iOS 9.0 (13A4293g) - DeviceType: iPad 2


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x06937632 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x068ff4a8 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x066a247d abort + 156
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0624fae7 abort_message + 151
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x06270683 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x025960d7 _objc_terminate() + 108
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0626dd0d std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 14
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0626d93e __cxa_rethrow + 103
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x02595fce objc_exception_rethrow + 47
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x029e3fe0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 672
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x029e3d2b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x021af30e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
12  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x01e2c257 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 471
13  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x01e2c45d -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 129
14  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x01e2d0e9 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1325
15  Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool  0x00058753 0x57000 + 5971
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x065f5a21 start + 1


Last command:
_ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:

Backtrace of last command:
  0  0x000000011b7ca76d -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  1  0x000000011b7ca632 __74-[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  2  0x00007fff8cd02c45 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff8cd036f2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
  4  0x000000010e3d7370 DVTDispatchSync (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x000000011b7ca555 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x000000011ca0273a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000011ca17fde (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000011cb48b8c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000011cb4547e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 10  0x000000011b9491fa -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibLayoutInset] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x000000011b949606 -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibLayoutBounds] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x000000011b9496bc -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibLayoutFrame] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x000000011b95c631 -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibLoggingDescription] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x000000011b95c80d -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibDefaultSubtreeDescription] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x0000000117ea1f90 -[NSObject(IBAutolayoutObjectIntegration) ibRecursivelyAddSubtreeDescriptionToString:indentation:layoutInfo:withIteratorBlock:andAdditionalDescriptionsBlock:] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
 16  0x0000000117ea22d3 -[NSObject(IBAutolayoutObjectIntegration) ibSubtreeDescriptionWithLayoutInfo:withIteratorBlock:startingIndentation:andAdditionalDescriptionsBlock:] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
 17  0x0000000117e79729 -[IBAutolayoutArbitrationUnit debugDescription] (in IBAutolayoutFoundation)
 18  0x000000011c9d1428 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 19  0x000000011b7a6e51 +[IBPlatformToolFailureHandler failureHandlerWithContext:failure:diagnosticsHandlerBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x000000011c9d2022 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 21  0x000000011b6a2e9e __72-[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager updateAutolayoutStatusInArbitrationUnits:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x000000011b69bd33 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager _runAutolayoutCommandForArbitrationUnits:withBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x000000011b6a2da5 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager updateAutolayoutStatusInArbitrationUnits:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x000000011b6a31c5 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager didFireAutolayoutStatusDelayedInvocation:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x000000010e22afc8 -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 26  0x000000010e22b53a -[DVTDelayedInvocation invokeIfNeeded] (in DVTFoundation)
 27  0x000000010e22bb17 -[DVTDelayedInvocation invoke] (in DVTFoundation)
 28  0x000000011b6a24ef -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager autolayoutStatusForArbitrationUnitContainingObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29  0x000000011b69ef36 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager isItemMisplaced:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30  0x000000011b69f4f9 __61-[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager itemsWithCleanAutolayoutStatus]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31  0x0000000117f5bfde -[NSSet(IBSetAdditions) ib_setByFilteringUsingBlock:] (in IBFoundation)
 32  0x000000011b69f49e -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager itemsWithCleanAutolayoutStatus] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 33  0x000000011b6a3470 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager preserveCleanAutolayoutStatusDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34  0x000000011b6861e4 -[IBDocument preserveCleanAutolayoutStatusDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35  0x000000011b86ceec -[IBResourceManager synchronizeObjectPropertyValuesWithVariantContext] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36  0x000000011b86a400 __66-[IBResourceManager setupVariantContextWithContainerRepositories:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37  0x000000010fb9452c -[IDEMediaResourceVariantContext registerVariantContextObserverWithOptions:block:] (in IDEKit)
 38  0x000000011b869fb2 -[IBResourceManager setupVariantContextWithContainerRepositories:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 39  0x000000011b86a557 -[IBResourceManager setResourceProvidingContainer:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40  0x000000011b65ffda -[IBDocument setResourceProvidingContainer:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41  0x000000011b65ec9d -[IBDocument refreshWorkspaceSourcedContent] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 42  0x000000011b65ef63 -[IBDocument registerWorkspaceDocument:forEditorViewController:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 43  0x000000011b53b940 -[IBAbstractDocumentEditor viewDidInstall] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 44  0x000000011b8c9355 -[IBStoryboardDocumentEditor viewDidInstall] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45  0x000000010ea565f8 -[DVTViewController _didInstallContentView:] (in DVTKit)
 46  0x000000010e842345 -[DVTControllerContentView _viewDidInstall] (in DVTKit)
 47  0x000000010e841be2 -[DVTControllerContentView viewDidMoveToWindow] (in DVTKit)
 48  0x00007fff97ceb33e -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 49  0x00007fff97cf605b -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 50  0x00007fff97ea6533 -[NSView setSubviews:] (in AppKit)
 51  0x000000010e834ac8 -[DVTBorderedView setContentView:] (in DVTKit)
 52  0x000000010f59a2cd -[IDEEditorContext _setEditorView] (in IDEKit)
 53  0x000000010f7424e0 -[IDEEditorContext setupNewEditor:] (in IDEKit)
 54  0x000000010f743dc9 __91-[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 55  0x000000010f5a976b -[IDEEditorContext _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard:] (in IDEKit)
 56  0x000000010f5a923b -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 57  0x000000010f5dba67 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:documentExtension:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 58  0x000000010f745698 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
 59  0x000000010f61ae82 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 60  0x000000010f61a739 -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 61  0x000000010f61a59a -[IDEEditorContext openEditorOpenSpecifier:] (in IDEKit)
 62  0x000000010f61a480 -[IDEEditorModeViewController openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:] (in IDEKit)
 63  0x000000010f61a2cc -[IDEEditorArea _openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 64  0x000000010f783756 __108+[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 65  0x000000010f61a16d +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenWithWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:allowFallback:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 66  0x000000010f619a39 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 67  0x000000010f6195bf -[_IDEOpenRequest _runIfNecessary] (in IDEKit)
 68  0x00007fff9781efd8 __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 69  0x00007fff892da5d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 70  0x00007fff892da263 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 71  0x00007fff893571ba __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 72  0x00007fff89295e21 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 73  0x00007fff89295488 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 74  0x00007fff96cdc701 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 75  0x00007fff96cdc497 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 76  0x00007fff96cdc2d7 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 77  0x00007fff97d4469b _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 78  0x00007fff981115d9 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 79  0x000000010e9555fe -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 80  0x00007fff97d3a54c -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 81  0x00007fff97cbc6e2 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 82  0x00007fff8d8f55ad start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

Comment: I think : In the question there is answer "Go to

/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

 and remove the profiles in there. Restart Xcode and it should work!"  The Library folder should be hidden. Please check it

Comment: @AshishKakkad But I don't have that folder

Comment: Go to your Finder > Go Menu (Press Alt) > Library

Comment: @AshishKakkad when I click coreSimulator, there is no folder for profiles, just "devices"

Comment: You should post the console output of the crash if you want a precise answer. Otherwise, you're poking around in the dark and guessing.

Comment: @AdrianB I posted the error when it crashes. I couldn't include the whole thing becuase it goes over the character limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your log, it looks like the problem lies here:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <AVPlayerViewController 0x7c84ee00> for the key path "playerController.hasEnabledAudio" from <AVPlayerViewController 0x7c84ee00> because it is not registered as an observer.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here's a post covering that topic you might find helpful.

[NSNotification removeObserver problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961828/nsnotification-removeobserver-problem)

**Update**

I'm not sure what your code looks like, but the console's output is telling you where the problem is. In terms of figuring out where the problem is, I'd put a breakpoint in before the crash. For example, if you've got an `IBAction` tied to a `UIButton`, put a breakpoint in and step through it to see what line is causing the problem.

In terms of finding answers, you're going to find that Objective-C is the road that's more well-traveled. For most things, the syntax is fairly similar to Swift, so if you find a potential solution in Objective-C, chances are you'll be able to cobble together an equivalent Swift line.

You may find these "cheat sheets" to be helpful:

[RW Swift Cheat Sheet](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73967/swift-cheat-sheet-and-quick-reference)

[RW Objective-C Cheat Sheet](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4872/objective-c-cheat-sheet-and-quick-reference)

If you can isolate the problematic function/method in your project, you probably want to include that in your question along with the console output upon crashing.

Comment: But that's for objective c

Comment: The syntax is a little different, but not that much.

Comment: I don't understand what I need to do / change?

Comment: I'm not dealing with NSNotificationCenter though

Comment: @yzet00 Updated w/ some things to try to isolate your problem

Comment: I added another message that I got, if that helps.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a `UIViewController` without a segue configured or a storyboard id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531035/xcode-scene-is-unreachable-due-to-lack-of-entry-points-but-cant-find-it

Comment: That might be the problem, but I have no way to access the storyboard though, my main problem.